# En SQL, ¿SET time_zone funciona para una tabla o toda la base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Al exportar una tabla de MySQL, este fue el resultado:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.4.10
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Servidor: localhost:8889
-- Tiempo de generación: 18-04-2018 a las 21:18:37
-- Versión del servidor: 5.5.42
-- Versión de PHP: 7.0.0

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "-05:00";

...
```

Mi duda es ¿Al ejecutar esto sólo altera la tabla que se crea o toda la base de datos?

Comment: Si la seteas como la estas seteando en la pregunta entonces solo afectara a tu conexion y expirara en el momento en el que cierres sesion. Si en lugar de eso usas la sentencia `SET GLOBAL time_zone = timezone` entonces afectara a todo el servidor, pero para esto necesitas privilegios especiales

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para responder a tu pregunta conviene entender que MySQL maneja varios tipos de configuración de zona horaria:

1. **zona horaria de sistema**
2. **zona horaria actual del servidor**
3. **zona horaria por conexión**

En consecuencia, cuando tú usas:

```
SET time_zone = "-05:00";
```

lo que haces es establecer una **zona horaria por conexión**. O sea, la posibilidad 3 mencionada más arriba:

> #### Zonas horarias por conexión
>
> Cada cliente que se conecta tiene su
>   propia configuración de zona horaria, dada por la variable de sesión
>   `time_zone`. Inicialmente, la variable de sesión toma su valor de la
>   variable global `time_zone`, pero el cliente puede cambiar su propia
>   zona horaria con esta declaración:
>
> ```
> SET time_zone = timezone;
> ```
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[Documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html)</sub>

Para completar la información, te pondré como funcionan las otras configuraciones:

> #### La zona horaria del sistema.
>
> Cuando se inicia el servidor, intenta determinar la zona horaria de la
>   máquina host y la usa para establecer la variable del sistema
>   `system_time_zone`. El valor no cambia después de eso.
>
> Puede configurar la zona horaria del sistema para el servidor MySQL al
>   inicio con la opción `--timezone = timezone_name` en [mysqld_safe](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld-safe.html).
>   También puede establecerlo configurando la variable de entorno `TZ`
>   antes de iniciar [mysqld](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld.html). Los valores permitidos para `--timezone`
>   o `TZ` dependen del sistema. Consulte la documentación de su sistema
>   operativo para ver qué valores son aceptables.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[Documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html)</sub>

---

> #### La zona horaria actual del servidor.
>
> La variable del sistema global `time_zone` indica la zona horaria en la que el servidor está
>   operando actualmente. El valor inicial para `time_zone` es `'SYSTEM'`,
>   que indica que la zona horaria del servidor es la misma que la zona
>   horaria del sistema.
>
> El valor de la zona horaria del servidor global inicial se puede
>   especificar explícitamente al inicio con la opción
>   `--default-time-zone = timezone` en la línea de comandos, o puede usar
>   la siguiente línea en un archivo de opciones:
>
> ```
> default-time-zone='timezone'
> ```
>
> Si tiene el privilegio `SUPER`, puede establecer el valor de la zona
>   horaria del servidor global en tiempo de ejecución con esta
>   instrucción:
>
> ```
> SET GLOBAL time_zone = timezone;
> ```
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[Documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html)</sub>

---

### Conclusión

De todo lo dicho podemos deducir que la zona horaria se establece a nivel de servidor, no a nivel de tabla. Y que el alcance de la misma puede ser parcial (por sesión) o global, según el caso.